# Подходит ли Android Studio для создания игр

Tags: android, android-studio

Много гуглил так и не нашел ответа , скажет пожалуйста подходил ли Android Studio для создания каких нибудь обычных игры по типу кликкеров и тд?

Comment: весьма станный вопрос. Ответ вроде однозначно подходит.

Comment: если на движке какой-нибудь Unity, то там свой софт, а если вы собираетесь делать что то простое, больше похожее на обычное приложение, чем полноценную игру, то Android Studio не только подходит, но и специально создана для этого

Answer (score 3):

Подходит, но Android Studio - это инструмент для создания, организации и отладки кода. В относительно сложных играх такие вещи как спрайты, например, создаются в графических редакторах, а уже потом импортируются в Android Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Подходит. Обратите внимание на Libgdx, отличный фреймворк для создания игр. Также по нему множество туториалов в т.ч. и русскоязычных. Например то что вы искали, [игра-кликер](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e75He5HE9iE).

Как дополнительный плюс - фреймворк кроссплатформенный.